# Microsoft Teams - deeplink from android app with specified date

Tags: android, android-intent, microsoft-teams, deep-linking, teams-toolkit

I am trying to create a deeplink to Microsoft Teams app from my android app with already selected startDate.

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-workflow?tabs=teamsjs-v2#deep-link-to-open-a-meeting-scheduling-dialog I managed to create below snippet of code

```
String uri = "msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/new?subject=testSubject&content=testContent&startTime=12%2F07%2F2023%2010%3A30%3A00";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri parsedUri = Uri.parse(uri);
intent.setData(parsedUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

**subject** and **content** are successfully set in Microsoft Teams scheduling dialog, but **startDate** is not.

What is the required formatting for **startDate** parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format for a deep link that you can to open a meeting scheduling dialog:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/new?subject=<meeting subject>&startTime=<date>&endTime=<date>&content=<content>&attendees=<user1>,<user2>,<user3>
```

**startTime**: Start time should be in long ISO 8601 format, for example 2018-03-12T23:55:25+02:00.

We have tried with the below API as well:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/new?subject=testSubject&content=testContent&startTime=12%2F07%2F2023%2010%3A30%3A00
```

It is showing correctly:-
[image]

Could you please try to simply run deeplink and check it once it is showing the start date or not?

Comment: Screenshot you made looks like desktop version of Microsoft Teams. It works as expected on my desktop too, however I wanted to do it on android device.
Difference between our deeplinks is prefix "msteams://" vs "https://". Sadly changing it to "https://" on android device results in not even opening Teams application.

Comment: We have tested this with android as well,It is workinf fine-https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/assets/93527375/13250fba-e110-40e1-8bc7-3d895126f9bd
Microsoft Teams Version-1416/1.0.0.2023072702/0416
Android Version-8.1.0
Could you please check it once the above version?

Comment: Ok, I see that "https://" version works if it is in CHAT of Microsoft Teams app. I want to navigate from my android app to Microsoft Teams android app.
Also on video you attached startTime is wrong. Deeplink has 10:30, and scheduling dialoog is open with 12:30

Comment: We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any update.